# To copy string value from text file and update the value in json file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to copy the string value xbeyhwvftwyfd6eg328302ye03hdn32 from Password field of abc.txt :

abc.txt:

```
{"Hello":"WORLD","OCEAN":"depth","Password":"xbeyhwvftwyfd6eg328302ye03hdn32","Cyclone":"no"}
```

And the Password value should be updated in the file.json file :

file.json :

```
{
   "requisite":{
            "Name": "user"
               },
             "Infrastructure":  {
                            "Password":  
                        },
}
```

How can I achieve this in powershell?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
param(
    $abcFileName = "d:\abc.txt",
    $fileFSONFileName = "d:\file.json"
) 

@'
{"Hello":"WORLD","OCEAN":"depth","Password":"xbeyhwvftwyfd6eg328302ye03hdn32","Cyclone":"no"}
'@ | Out-File $abcFileName

@'
{
   "requisite":{
      "Name":"user"
   },
   "Infrastructure":{
      "Password":""
   }
}
'@ | Out-File $fileFSONFileName

$hash = (Get-Content $fileFSONFileName | ConvertFrom-Json)
$hash.Infrastructure.Password = (Get-Content $abcFileName | ConvertFrom-Json).Password
$hash | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $fileFSONFileName
```

content of JSON d:\file.json

```json
{
    "requisite":  {
                      "Name":  "user"
                  },
    "Infrastructure":  {
                           "Password":  "xbeyhwvftwyfd6eg328302ye03hdn32"
                       }
}

``
```

Comment: I want to copy Password field from abc.txt and copy to file.json Password key value

Comment: abc.txt is well formed json

Comment: I cant take the correct Password value from abc.txt and update the in file.json

Comment: Why we get Invalid json primitive?

Comment: In the above solution , ```$hash = (Get-Content $fileFSONFileName | ConvertFrom-Json)
$hash.Infrastructure.Password = (Get-Content $abcFileName | ConvertFrom-Json).Password``` the value would be updated . However, the content is not being set to back to json and Invalid json primitive error is displayed

Comment: in the above solution all works corectly, use valudators for you input files, like this https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/